# Two Solid Color Background at a Fixed Position

Tags: css, layout, background, gradient

I've been trying to look around as I know there are a lot of questions, tutorials, tools to achieve a two solid background but the problem is that I can't achieve a simple design.

My Layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4qO7.jpg

**What I exactly can't achieve:**

1. Having the grey color start at the middle of the first box no matter what the resolution is and I'm unable to do that with the Gradient tool.
2. Make that shadow like effect disappear when I apply it using CSS.

**Here's what I achieved so far:**

```
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0, White 370px, white 301px, #818285 301px, #818285 300px, #818285 100%) no-repeat;
```

I hope you can look at my question as different not as a duplicate because I've been looking for a while with no success to find a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

By adding **percentages** after you set the colors in your `linear-gradient` property, you can achieve this affect:

```css
html, body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; background:#000; }

#container{ 
  width:95%;
  height:90%; 
  margin:auto;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient( #fff 0%, #fff 40%, #999 40%, #999 100% );
  background:linear-gradient( #fff 0%, #fff 40%, #999 40%, #999 100% );

  /*Vertical Align*/
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY( -50% );
}

#content{
  width:80%;
  height:80%; 
  background-color:#eee;
  margin:auto;
  
  /*Vertical Align*/
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY( -50% );
}

p{ 
  margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; 
  
  /*Vertical Align*/
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY( -50% );
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content"><p>Div Content Here<p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The more stops or color transitions you add, the crisper this effect should be.

Comment: Thanks Lynel for your answer, however this is a 50% 50% background. In my design the two colors are not equal and also I need the point where the grey starts to be fixed regardless the resolution of the screen or the height of my page.

Comment: I just edited my answer to offset the two colors by 40% and 60% respectivly. Notice I've used 4 stops now, and set each percent accordingly. You can offset your colors to any degree using this technique. Also, what do you mean the gray area needs to be fixed?

Comment: I mean that if the default height of the page is x and the content fills it to become 2x, then using this technique will change the grey part to start below the middle of the first box in my content area. and also the page height is is just 0.5x then the grey part of the background might start from right below the menu. which will compromise the layout look.

Comment: I'm not sure entirely what you are asking but the div will grow taller with content, stretching your du-color scheme with it. So yes, the point where the two colors meet will gradually move down the page, but it will always be proportionate to the containing div - The top part will never get larger than 40% and the bottom never more or less than 60%.

Comment: Lynel, Thank you so much for your time but I was able to figure out a work around for my problem. I posted it as an answer. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used a work around I'm not sure if this is a clean fix but It's diffidently what I want.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="bg_2"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: grey;
}

.bg_2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
```

This method helped me achieving a clean separation between the two colors because I don't know why the gradient technique leaves a soft shadow effect between the stops which is not very neat. Also the grey part of my background will start always at a fixed position.

*Bonus: If you need to build the background to move will scrolling to maintain the two color background no matter the height of the page you can change the position from absolute to fixed.*